# in Elementor how to make scroll snap just for some containers not all page

Tags: css, elementor, scroll-snap

I tried to apply some CSS on first of 3 containers and it worked fine, but the fourth container - which has no scroll snap - is not scrolling smoothly. Its kind if stuck under the third container.

Many thanks in advance.

I used this code in an Elementor page:

```
/* Set the root element for scroll snap */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/* Apply scroll snap effect to the container */
.scroll-snap-container {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Just add `scroll-snap-container` class to the 4th container and it will work.</strike>

EDIT:

The situation is that **there is no background** on the 4th container, and the attachment is fixed for the entire site, hence the background "repeats" itself, **so the effect won't be seen** until you add a background to the container.

You also have to add the following CSS code to the containers after the 3rd:

```
scroll-snap-align: start;
```

Comment: Thank ugroi for answer, Scroll snap effect should be attached to only number 1, 2, and 3 containers, I want other containers to be normal, no scroll snap effect. so I added the class to the first three containers and not the others. but I end up with that problem.

Comment: I've edited my answer. In short: you have to add a background and `scroll-snap-align: start;` to the container(s).

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that using the premium addons for elementor plugin.
It has a vertical scroll widget that allows to have the scroll snap only on the sections inside the widget.

You can see the tutorial here: 
[Vertical Scroll Widget Tutorial](https://premiumaddons.com/docs/vertical-scroll-widget-tutorial/)